# How to clear text inside text field when radio button is select

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, radio-button

Currently I have this radio buttons

1. Eletronics
2. Computers
3. Others

What I am trying to do is, if radio button `Others` is selected, I would like to display an input text field and let the user type.

What I would like to do is, when I select `Others` and type something inside the input field, then when I choose back to `Eletronics` or `Computers`, I would like to clear the text that I wrote inside input field.

Please kindly provide me with the solution of JavaScript or jQuery.

Here is my code sample. Please kindly check it: http://jsfiddle.net/dnGKM/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

```
$('input:radio').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == 'others') {
        $('#showhide').css('opacity', 1.0);
   } else {
       $('#showhide').css('opacity', 0).find('input:text#others_text').val('');
    }  
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dnGKM/8/)

Comment: When I submit the result through POST, result for Others text box is always blank :( .. any idea why ? If i remove the js code which is find('input:text').val('');, data are submitted correctly, not blank data anymore. Any ways around for the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
document.getElementById("others_text").value='';
```

to clear the input field.

Answer (score 1):

Please add below code of line in your code:

```
document.getElementById("others_text").value = '';
```

now its look like:

```
document.getElementById("others").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    document.getElementById("others_text").value = '';
    document.getElementById("showhide").style.opacity = 1;
}, false);
document.getElementById("computers").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    document.getElementById("showhide").style.opacity = 0;
}, false);
document.getElementById("electronics").addEventListener("click", function()
{
    document.getElementById("showhide").style.opacity = 0;
}, false);​
```

This would be helpful for you.

Comment: the problem is, when i submitting the form with POST, i only get the blank value. I choose "Others" there's input text inside text field though. :( . Is there any other way to clear the text?

Answer (score 1):

You add the `jQuery` tag to your question, so that should do the trick using jQuery :)

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="electronics">Electronics</label>
<input type="radio" id="electronics" name="rdbutton" />
<label for="computers">Computers</label>
<input type="radio" id="computers" name="rdbutton" />
<label for="others">Others</label>
<input type="radio" id="others" name="rdbutton" />
<input type="text" id="others-text" name="others-text" class="hidden" />
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('id') == 'others') {
            $('#others-text').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('#others-text').addClass('hidden');
            $('#others-text').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah sorry, my fault, I didn't know that was forbidden. Just edited my answer, I did it a more common way :)

Comment: When I submit the result through POST, result for Others text box is always blank :( .. any idea why ? If i remove the js code which is this ($('#others-text').val('');), data are submitted correctly, not blank data anymore. Any ways around for the solution ?

Comment: The name of the text-box is `others-text`, so you have to use `$_GET['others-text']` (PHP) or `request.getParameter("others-text")` (JAVA). Is that what you did?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this Solution:

```
$(function() {
      $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'others') {
           $('#others-text').show();
       } else {
           $('#others-text').hide();
           $('#others-text').val('');
       }
   });
})
```

Here there is a JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/dnGKM/4/

Comment: the problem is, when i submitting the form with POST, i only get the blank value. I choose "Others" there's input text inside text field though. :( . Is there any other way to clear the text?

Comment: i have updated JSFiddle.See this link if it can help u:
    http://jsfiddle.net/dnGKM/5/

Answer (score 1):

===============HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="rdo" value="1" checked="checked" />Electronics
<input type="radio" name="rdo" value="2" />Computers
<input type="radio" name="rdo" value="3" />Others
```

===============jQuery

```
  $('input[name=rdo]').change(function() {
         var a = $(this).val();
         if (a != 3) {
             $('#textboxid').hide();
         }else{
             $('#textboxid').val('');
             $('#textboxid').show();
         }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#<%=text1.ClientID%>").val('');
```