# Clearing a textbox field when a radio button is selected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox

I have a web form which allows users to donate money using the predefined radio buttons with a value assigned to them (all different numbers). I also have a choose your own amount textfield which they can write in a custom amount they wish to donate. I want to clear the custom textfield if a user selects a predefined choice.

So far I have created this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="3" checked="checked"> <strong>64</strong>
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="11" checked="checked"> <strong>100</strong>
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="32" checked="checked"> <strong>250</strong>
<input type="radio" value="" name="am_payment"><label>Other</label>
<input type="text" name="CP_otheramount" value="" id="theamount" disabled="disabled"/>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$('input[name="am_payment"]').on('click', function() {
   if ($(this).val() === '') {
      $('#theamount').removeProp("disabled");
   }
   else {
      $('#theamount').prop("disabled", "disabled");
      $('input[name="CP_otheramount"]').val("");
   }
});
```

But basing it on a `value === true` for `value=""` just doesn't seem right.

Is there a way to improve this?

Thanks

Comment: To enable disable the field use `$('#theamount').prop("disabled", true/false);`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uc5us2rj/1/ ?

Comment: `Go through the link` [Demo is here please check it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295393/how-to-clear-text-inside-text-field-when-radio-button-is-select)

Comment: Go through the link [Demo is here please check it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295393/how-to-clear-text-inside-text-field-when-radio-button-is-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable/enable an element you need to set the value of the disabled property to true/false, removing the property doesn't work so you need

```js
$('input[name="am_payment"]').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === '') {
    $('#theamount').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#theamount').prop("disabled", true).val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="3" checked="checked"> <strong>64</strong>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="11" checked="checked"> <strong>100</strong>

<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="32" checked="checked"> <strong>250</strong>

<input type="radio" value="" name="am_payment">
<label>Other</label>

<input type="text" name="CP_otheramount" value="" id="theamount" disabled="disabled" />
```

Comment: That works OK, the problem is that it forces users to use the radio buttons to select a choice. What if the user wants to just press the textbox to enter something too?

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeAttr` instead of `removeProp` and I have modified your code to accept amounts on textbox based on `radio` button selected

```js
$('input[name="am_payment"]').on('click', function() {
   if ($(this).val() === '') {
     $('input[name="CP_otheramount"]').val('');
      $('#theamount').removeAttr("disabled");
   }
   else {
      $('#theamount').prop("disabled", "disabled");
      $('input[name="CP_otheramount"]').val($(this).val());
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="3" checked="checked"> <strong>64</strong>
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="11" checked="checked"> <strong>100</strong>
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="32" checked="checked"> <strong>250</strong>
<input type="radio" value="" name="am_payment"><label>Other</label>
<input type="text" name="CP_otheramount" value="" id="theamount" disabled="disabled"/>
```

**Update**

From your comments I hope you are expecting below functionality.

```js
$('#theamount').on('focus', function() {
  $("input:radio").prop("checked",false);
  $("input[value='']").prop("checked",true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="3" checked="checked"> <strong>64</strong>
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="11" checked="checked"> <strong>100</strong>
<input type="radio" name="am_payment" value="32" checked="checked"> <strong>250</strong>
<input type="radio" value="" name="am_payment"><label>Other</label>
<input type="text" name="CP_otheramount" value="" id="theamount" disabled="disabled"/>
```

Comment: jQuery specification recommends using .prop("disabled", true/false) instead of adding and removing the property or attribute

Comment: This works quite nicely, one UX problem i have just noticed though. Rather than the textbox be disabled on startup, how about if the user presses inside the textbox the radio button next to it is selected? I would generally press the textbox rather than the radio button if i was going to enter an amount but if its disabled people might think its not working.